# How to calculate power of a number with decimal exponent in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am looking for a solution to calculate power of a number with a decimal exponent in XSLT 1.0. Currently the calculation method that i use calculates power only for non-decimal exponents. This is the template that i use currently:

```
<xsl:call-template name="Pow">
    <xsl:with-param name="Base" select="10"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="Exponent" select="2"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="Result" select="1"/>
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:template name="Pow">                   <!-- TODO: Handle decimal exponents -->
    <xsl:param name="Base"/>
    <xsl:param name="Exponent"/>
    <xsl:param name="Result"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$Exponent = 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$Exponent = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="$Result * $Base"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="Pow">
          <xsl:with-param name="Base" select="$Base"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="Exponent" select="$Exponent - 1"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="Result" select="$Result * $Base"/>
        </xsl:call-template>                          
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I don't necessarily need a generalized solution. I only need to find value of a number raised to the power `2.4`.

I tried to break down my problem as follows:

```
x ^ (2.4) = (x ^ 2) * (x ^ 0.4)
= (x ^ 2) * (x ^ (2/5))
= (x ^ 2) * ((x ^ 2) ^ 1/5)
```

Finding square of `x` can be done, so my problem breaks down to calculating the "5th root" of a number.

I also thought of breaking my problem into a logarithmic equation but didn't reached anywhere with that.

I am thinking of writing a code implementing the long-divison method of calculating roots but that seems highly inefficient and non-elegant.

Can anyone suggest me a more simpler and efficient way of solving my problem?
If not, then has anyone tried coding the long-divison method of calculating roots?

Thanx in advance!!

**Note:** this is a template that i would be using many many times in my execution so efficiency is all the more important for me.

Comment: Check whether the code presented in http://fxsl.sourceforge.net/articles/xslCalculator/The%20FXSL%20Calculator.html can be adapted to your needs or check whether your XSLT processor allows you to call an extension function in another language like Java or C# for instance where you could then call a mathematical function.

Comment: `x ^ 2.4` is not the same as `(x ^ 2) * (x ^ 0.4)` but is actually `(x ^ 0.2) ^ 12` (because 2.4 = 12 / 5).

Comment: @TimC we both are correct. i just tried to make it as simplified as possible.

Comment: @MartinHonnen i have already tried that. It only works with XSLT 2.0

Comment: I haven't checked the details but FXSL exists in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 versions.

Comment: @MartinHonnen ok i will check again but i seem to remember that it didn't worked for me earlier as well, maybe for some other reason.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't your processor support the EXSLT math:power() extension function? The following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
extension-element-prefixes="math">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="num" select="32" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:value-of select="math:power($num, 2.4)" />
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

**libxslt:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>4096</output>
```

**Saxon 6.5/Xalan**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>4095.9999999999986</output>
```